# Метод notifyItemInserted в Adapter не работает

Tags: java, android

В общем из-за невнимательности у меня создавалось 2 объекта одного фрагмента, поэтому был null и задания не добавлялись. Приношу извинения и говорю спасибо, кто пытался помочь.

**Код Activity**

```
public class ReminderActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                                implements CreatingTaskDialogFragment.CreatingTask {

    private SectionPagerReminderAdapter mSectionPagerReminderAdapter;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private CurrentFragment mCurrentFragment;
    private DoneFragment mDoneFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);

        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        setUI();

    }

    private void setUI() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionPagerReminderAdapter = new SectionPagerReminderAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionPagerReminderAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        mCurrentFragment = (CurrentFragment) mSectionPagerReminderAdapter.getItem(Constants.TAG_CURRENT);
        mDoneFragment = (DoneFragment) mSectionPagerReminderAdapter.getItem(Constants.TAG_DONE);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CreatingTaskDialogFragment taskDialogFragment =
                        new CreatingTaskDialogFragment();

                taskDialogFragment.show(mFragmentManager, Constants.TAG_CREATING_NEW_TASK);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_reminder, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_to_schedule:
                toActivity(Constants.TAG_TO_SCHEDULE);
                break;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                toActivity(Constants.TAG_TO_SETTINGS);
                break;

            case R.id.action_clean_up_everything:
                getAgree();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void getAgree() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        cleanUpEverything();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    private void cleanUpEverything() {
        // Добавить удаление тасков с активного фрагмента
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tasks deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void toActivity(int tag) {
        Intent intent;

        switch (tag) {
            case Constants.TAG_TO_SCHEDULE:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            case Constants.TAG_TO_SETTINGS:
                intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void taskCreated(Task newTask) {
        mCurrentFragment.addNewTask(newTask);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Task added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**CurrentFragment**

```
public class CurrentFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ReminderTaskAdapter mAdapter = new ReminderTaskAdapter();

    public CurrentFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCurrent);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void addNewTask(Task newTask) {
        mAdapter.addTask(newTask);
    }

}
```

**Код Dialog для создания задачи**

```
public class CreatingTaskDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private CreatingTask mCreatingTask;

    public interface CreatingTask {
        void taskCreated(Task newTask);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCreatingTask = (CreatingTask) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_task_create, null);

        final TextInputLayout tilTitle = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilTitle);
        final EditText editTitle = tilTitle.getEditText();

        final TextInputLayout tilMessage = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilMessage);
        final EditText editMessage = tilMessage.getEditText();

        TextInputLayout tilDate = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDate);
        final EditText editDate = tilDate.getEditText();

        TextInputLayout tilTime = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilTime);
        final EditText editTime = tilTime.getEditText();

        final Task newTask = new Task();

        if (editDate != null) {
            editDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // For editText click animation
                    if (editDate.length() == 0) {
                        editDate.setText(" ");
                    }

                    DialogFragment datePickerDialogFragment =
                                                new DatePickerDialogFragment() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view,
                                              int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                            date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                            editDate.setText(DateFormatter.getDate(date.getTimeInMillis()));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            editDate.setText(null);
                        }
                    };
                    datePickerDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), Constants.TAG_DATE_CALENDAR);
                    editDate.setText(null);
                }
            });
        }

        if (editTime != null) {
            editTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (editTime.length() == 0) {
                        editTime.setText(" ");
                    }

                    DialogFragment timePickerDialogFragment = new TimePickerDialogFragment() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                            time.set(0, 0, 0, hourOfDay, minute);
                            editTime.setText(DateFormatter.getTime(time.getTimeInMillis()));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            editTime.setText(null);
                        }
                    };
                    timePickerDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), Constants.TAG_TIME_CALENDAR);
                    editTime.setText(null);
                }
            });
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setView(container)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.creating_dialog_positive_button,
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (editTitle != null && editMessage != null
                                && editDate != null && editTime != null) {
                            newTask.setTitle(editTitle.getText().toString());
                            newTask.setMessage(editMessage.getText().toString());
                            newTask.setDate(editDate.getText().toString());
                            newTask.setTime(editTime.getText().toString());
                        }
                        mCreatingTask.taskCreated(newTask);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.creating_dialog_negative_button,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                final Button positiveButton =
                        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

                if (editTitle.length() == 0) {
                    positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                    tilTitle.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.til_title_error_message));
                }

                editTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (editTitle.length() == 0) {
                            positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                            tilTitle.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.til_title_error_message));
                        } else {
                            positiveButton.setEnabled(true);
                            tilTitle.setErrorEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

**Код Adapter**

```
public class ReminderTaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Task> mTasks = new ArrayList<>();

    private TaskViewHolder taskHolder;
    private Task task;

    public void addTask(Task newTask) {
        mTasks.add(newTask);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_cardview,
                parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskTitle);
        TextView message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskMessage);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskDate);
        TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskTime);

        return new TaskViewHolder(view, title, message, date, time);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        task = mTasks.get(position);

        taskHolder = (TaskViewHolder) holder;

        taskHolder.mTitle.setText(task.getTitle());
        taskHolder.mMessage.setText(task.getMessage());
        taskHolder.mDate.setText(task.getDate());
        taskHolder.mTime.setText(task.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTasks.size();
    }

    private class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTitle, mMessage, mDate, mTime;

        public TaskViewHolder(View itemView, TextView title,
                              TextView message, TextView date, TextView time) {
            super(itemView);
            mTitle = title;
            mMessage = message;
            mDate = date;
            mTime = time;
        }
    }
}
```

В Adapter не хочет работать метод `notifyItemInserted`.

Comment: если ошибка в этой строке `mAdapter.addTask(newTask);`, то вы вызываете `addNewTask` раньше, чем вызывается `onCreateView`

Comment: Я тоже об этом думал, но у меня есть пример, на который я ориентируюсь, так там такая реализация этого класса спокойно работает. Вот мне интересно, почему там работает, а у меня нет. Приводить оттуда код нет смысла, ибо он абсолютно такой же.

Comment: Дело в том, что **я не знаю**, какой там код. И никто не знает. Покажите код, где вы вызыватет addNewTask

Comment: Я добавил всю цепочку создания - от диалога до адаптера. Если вынести создание адаптера в другое место, например, при объявлении самой переменной адаптера, то всё работает, но задача не создается. Мне кажется, что метод notifyItemInserted попросту не работает.

Comment: `Task` это просто модель данных?.. Я так и не нашёл у вас в коде где же вы собственно добавляете элемент в адаптер.Судя по тому, что я увидел, у вас 0 элементов в списке данных адаптера и вы никогда ничего туда не добавляете.

Comment: Да, Task это модель данных, которые записываются туда из диалога. Затем объект Task добавляется в List в адаптере в методе addTask (самый первый метод в адаптере).

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ самостоятельно, не надо писать в заголовке РЕШЕНО и объяснять что-то в вопросе, лучшим вариантом будет опубликовать свое решение в качестве ответа. Если вам лень или вы считаете свое решение эксклюзивным - оставьте свой вопрос, как есть. В общем то никому не надо знать, решили ли его конкретно ВЫ - для опубликованного здесь вопроса важно только опубликованное здесь же решение.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это ответ на другой вопрос.